# automator to run AppleScript for a shell script

Tags: applescript, automator, perl

For a selected file in Finder, I like to run a perl script using Services. I created an Automator process that runs an AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "/Users/myaccountname/Applications/TeXcount_3_0/texcount.pl \"" & (input as string) & "\""
    end tell
end run
```

The only problem is that the selected filename appears as something like:

```
"Macintosh HD:Users:myaccountname:Documents:texfile.tex"
```

which the perl script cannot understand. How can I make it a UNIX-like filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to get the POSIX path of the input file:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "/Users/myaccountname/Applications/TeXcount_3_0/texcount.pl \"" & ( POSIX path of input as string) & "\""
    end tell
end run
```

I found the answer over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749119/why-does-this-line-run-fine-in-script-editor-but-not-on-the-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `quoted form of` to escape the arguments:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "printf %s\\\\n " & quoted form of POSIX path of item 1 of input & ">/tmp/a"
    end tell
end run
```

Or if the service can receive multiple files as input:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set args to ""
    repeat with f in input
        set args to args & " " & quoted form of POSIX path of f
    end repeat
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "printf %s\\\\n " & args & ">/tmp/a"
    end tell
end run
```